# Scrollbars on almost every browser in windows (not Mac)

Tags: css, windows, macos, scrollbars

I have a div which serves as a popup (absolute position etc.).
Now that I'm testing on different platform I see that in almost every browser on Windows I get scrollbars, even though there is nothing to scroll... not on Mac though.
I enclosed an image, it's just one of many cases.
I don't want those scrollbars, what can I do?
I tried overflow: hidden; and googled a lot but couldn't seem to find a solution! Any help much appreciated!

[image: this is the right end of a div I use as a "popup"]

Comment: Aren't scrollbars on Mac OS X hidden anyway and only visible if you actually scroll?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this too; a continued Google found this:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow/

The trick for me was setting the div overflow to hidden.
I didn't realize it was still set to "scroll" in my CSS which apparently renders scrollbars even if unnecessary on a PC browser (tried with Chrome and IE) but not on any of the Mac OS browsers I used (Safari, Firefox, Chrome, and Opera)

Here are the div options:
    div {
      overflow:  visible | hidden | scroll | auto | inherit
    }

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your actual code it's hard to be sure, but more than likely you have the property `overflow: visible` prescribed somewhere in your CSS which would force the navigation to display.

If so, you'll want to change `overflow: visible` to `overflow: auto`, which will only display a scroll bar if the page/element needs to scroll.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what ekfuhrmann said, if you change the `overflow` value to `overflow: auto` then it will only display the scrollbar when it is necessary.

You can also be very specific with your scrollbar by doing `overflow-x: auto`, `overflow-y: hidden`.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to create a popup, you could instead use `position: fixed`, but that is irrelevant to what you are asking.

I would suggest using Chrome Developer Tools to figure out what exactly the scrollbar is attached to. That should help you figure out where the problem lies.

Comment: Thx D34... yeah i tried that, it can't be located, I really think it's something Windows does, because it's in all the browsers on Windows.

Comment: @Melvin  Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @user2168130 sorry for the late reply. unfortunately i couldn't find a decent solution.